# Why is jQuery toggle continually changing on mouse movement/hover

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, show-hide

I've just got this bit of code working in jQuery via an answer on here -

```
$('.folder-items a').hover(function(){
   $(this).siblings('.file-hover').toggle();
});​
```

the `.folder-items` a is within a li. I want to be able to hover the whole 'li' and not just on the actual `<a>` to show the `.file-hover` div.

I've created this in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8Sefc/8/ - but when moving my mouse around the li it's showing/hiding like crazy...

I think it's something up with my CSS and display: block; width: 100%; of the li and li a but can't work out another way to do this...

Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that the elements to be shown are "on top" of the hovered element is causing trouble. I'd suggest, as an alternative, to only show the element during the hover, hiding them when **they** are hovered out:

```
$('.folder-items a').hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.file-hover').show();
}).siblings('.file-hover').hover(
    function() { },
    function() { $(this).hide(); }
);
```

**Update:** this is not a perfect solution. If you move your mouse like crazy over the itens, sometimes they will "stick" and not disappear... Maybe a better solution would be to bind the hover to the **parent** element instead:

```
$('.folder-items a').parent().hover(
    function(){
        $(this).children('.file-hover').show();
    },
    function(){
         $(this).children('.file-hover').hide();
         $(this).children('a').show();
    }
);
```

I tested this with your fiddle, and it seems allright.

Comment: Why use `hover()` with an empty function when you can just call `mouseleave`?

Comment: @JaredFarrish it *kinda* works, but have the same problem of my original answer (elements not hiding when they should). Check my update.

Comment: I don't know, I think `.parent()` is probably unnecessary. http://jsfiddle.net/8Sefc/19/

Comment: Also, and this is a comment on what's happening on the screen, hiding the information that identifies the file you've hovered over is a bit weird.

Comment: @mgibsonbr I've fixed that problem in my updated answer: http://jsfiddle.net/8Sefc/21/

Comment: And it probably should be [`.has('.file-hover')`](http://jsfiddle.net/8Sefc/22/).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you're right, I didn't know about mouseleave, in fact I never used (mouseover,mouseout,mouseenter,mouseleave). For me it's simpler to use one method for all, but I guess it's a matter of opinion...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because when you only supply `toggle()` with one function, that function is called on both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events - [further information](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover2)

If you change your code to use `mouseenter()` and add another handler to the `.file-hover` elements to hide them on `mouseleave()` it should work as you are expecting it to:

```
$('.folder-items > li > a').mouseenter(function() {
    $(".file-hover").hide();
    $(this).siblings('.file-hover').show();
});

$(".file-hover").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8Sefc/21/)

**Update**
I've also included a method to fix the issue which mgibsonbr mentioned where the hover state is not removed when the mouse is scanned across the elements quickly.

Comment: Also your css has something wrong, you're declaring `.folder-items a { float: left; width:100%; }` and then `.file-hover a { float: right; }`, you wanna float right or left?

Comment: @StuartRobson Use `mouseenter()` instead of `hover()`

Comment: @StuartRobson I've just updated my answer for you, along with your fiddle. This should work for you now.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters, I would suggest changing

```
$('.folder-items a').hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.file-hover').toggle();
});​
```

to something like

```
$('.folder-items a').hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.file-hover').show();
}, function(){
    $(this).siblings('.file-hover').hide();
});​
```